# File Parsing in java SQLite

Tags: sqlite, parsing, text-files, javaparser

I want to parse a file and store reference of each bible verse. file format is:
1:1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

1:2 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon
the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the
waters.

1:3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.

1:4 And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light
from the darkness.

1:5 And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night.
And the evening and the morning were the first day.

1:6 And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters,
and let it divide the waters from the waters.

1:7 And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were
under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament:
and it was so.

1:8 And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the
morning were the second day.

Note: there is a line break after each line.

Comment: This is not related to javaparser. Javaparser is a library to specifically parse Java source code. Perhaps you could instead being interested in a parser generator such as ANTLR. However your case is so simple that you can use some regular expression

Comment: Thanks  Federico Tomassetti. you are right. i figured it out.